# Plone website: Add spanish character?

Tags: user-input

We have a Plone website and I am simply a user - managing content.

I am trying to figure out how to add Spanish characters like accents and the tilde over the n.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why am I getting down voted on this?  It is a simple question.  I had searched the internet and this board for an answer before I asked.

Comment: Laura, it looks like your initial post was misinterpreted as too general, probably due to the typo (since corrected) that had "Phone" for "Plone".

Comment: Okay thanks Steve.  And thank you for your edits - why did you erase where I got here from (plone.org) and my name?  I disagree with the edit that says that my post has "nothing to do with plone".  Your answer, which is correct, is plone specific.

Comment: Hi, Laura. Stackoverflow questions are ideally focused on the problem. How you reached stackoverflow isn't relevant to that and increases the chance of getting down or close votes.

The person who thought the question had nothing to do with Plone was interpreting it as answerable with general information on how to enter accented characters in any entry field. Not an unreasonable interpretation.

Comment: Thank you Steve! I am obviously a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by 'phone website'
However, this is how you type accents and tilde over the n

Windows

```
á = Alt + 0225
é = Alt + 0233
í = Alt + 0237
ó = Alt + 0243
ú = Alt + 0250
ñ = Alt + 0241
ü = Alt + 0252
```

Mac

```
Opt + e, then a = á
Opt + e, then e = é
Opt + e, then i = í
Opt + e, then o = ó
Opt + e, then u = ú
Opt + n, then n = ñ
Opt + u, then u = ü
```

iPhone/Android

```
Tap and hold a specific letter 
(say, the letter "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "n") 
and a pop-up menu of accent marks will appear
```

Comment: Thanks I had tried this but it does not work on a Plone website for some reason!

Comment: @Laura, if you copy for instance `ñ` and paste it in Plone, it works?

Comment: Thanks Lea - but I have my answer already with Steve.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I am glad that you found the answer, Steve's answer is great!

Comment: You know what - I am an idiot.  I kept pressing "command" instead of "option" (I am using a mac).  This worked fine!!  And it is easy too.  Thanks!

Comment: Lol @Laura, Mac users lol. No worries. Make sure to accept Steve's or my answer and/or up vote the other answer. I think both answers are great! It might worth at least some up vote :)

Comment: I wish I could Lea.  I can't vote up since I don't have enough points and I don't see where to accept your or Steve's answer. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Lea Tano's answer is great, and those techniques should work in any field and pretty much any program.

For the visual editor in particular (body text), look for a button with an Omega symbol. That will open a popup that allows you to select from the international character set. If the button is absent, ask your site admin to enable the TinyMCE "custom character" button on the toolbar.